# Do I own the copyright to code I write for school projects?

Tags: licensing

I'm a student at a US college, and I've been assigned a programming project to complete on my own. I wrote a program to solve a somewhat complex problem, and I'd like to release it under an open-source license so that others can use it and learn from it. However, I'm not entirely sure to whom the code's copyright belongs. The class' syllabus says nothing about the ownership of code produced for the class, but I don't want to take any chances.

Do I own the code?

Comment: Ask the department head, nobody here's gonna know.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [licensing/legal advice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1699210)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If nothing is stated by the school that you signed and agreed to...copyright defaults to you, the author.

When you're paid it's a different set of rules - Look in the comments of this answer for some excellent resources from [Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c) and [outis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90527/outis).  With anything legal it's safest to get an opinion from the experts, in this case a lawyer.  (Always a good idea actually, water pipes broken? call a plumber)

Comment: You are probably correct in the first sentence, but for a real answer you should ask a lawyer.  The second sentence may not be true, depending on the nature of the work / employment contract, as well as explicit copyright clauses.

Comment: @Stephen:  That's the "unless..." portion :)  In either case you are right, better to be safe and get a legal opinion...answer updated.

Comment: "Legally right" might be true, but that still might get him expelled and cause him a ton of trouble and delay his degree by years while he fights a court battle

Comment: @Paul:  I don't debate that can be a cluster#$%^ situation, and a very important thing to be pointed out in this case, +1 from me.

Comment: @Nick - actually, my point is that **in the absence of a copyright clause**, you *may not* own copyright on code produced during contracted employment!!!  It depends on the nature of the work contract.

Comment: @Stephen - That's never been the case for me but I'm not a layer or a contract lifer...can you link to some resources on this?  I love to be better informed about...well, anything, whenever possible.

Comment: Here's one resource: http://www.bitlaw.com/copyright/ownership.html

Comment: And another: http://www.copylaw.com/new_articles/wfh.html

Comment: Both suggest that if the code was written as a contribution to a collective work, a translation (read: ported to another platform/language) or a supplementary work (a plugin, for example) it qualifies as "work for hire" and thus the commissioner of the work has the stronger copyright claim. If the coder wrote the entirety of the code and there's no explicit ownership clause, the coder should have the stronger claim on the source code, similar to how a novelist is the sole author of a book, even a commissioned one. Note that commissioners have usage rights, even if they don't own the copyright.

Comment: @Nick - here's another reference for you: http://fairuse.stanford.edu/Copyright_and_Fair_Use_Overview/chapter0/0-c.html#1  .  As I said, I think your (revised) assertion is false under some circumstances.  [And it is nice to see that my memory is still working :-) ]

Comment: @outis & @Stephen - Thanks!  Good resources...learn more every day.

Answer (score 4):

IANAL, I would assume it should be specified in University policies.

For instance, [University Policy Office](http://www.ucop.edu/ucophome/coordrev/) of [University of California](http://www.ucop.edu/) specifies [Copyright Ownership Policy](http://www.ucop.edu/ucophome/coordrev/policy/8-19-92att.html)

> This Policy is intended to embody the
>   spirit of academic tradition, which
>   provides copyright ownership to
>   faculty for their scholarly and
>   aesthetic copyrighted works, and is
>   otherwise consistent with the United
>   States Copyright Law, which provides
>   the University ownership of its
>   employment-related works

and such it is clarified to whom such policy applies, for example [ucop.edu](http://ucop.edu) says:

> This Policy applies to University
>   employees, students, and other persons
>   or entities using designated
>   University facilities

Now, regarding student work, it specifies as follows:

> Ownership of copyrights to student
>   works shall reside with the
>   originator.

where originator is also clearly defined:

> One who produces a work by his or her
>   own intellectual labor.

Given this example, I would ask your office of your university for presenting you with such policy document. If no document is available, I think you need to refer to your government law, but no policy shall mean copyright belongs inherently to you.

Comment: Student can't be the same as employee since student is the one paying.

Answer (score 2):

License it before you turn it in. :)

Do you think it's going to be a problem? What does the professor say? I'd just ask to see if it's going to be a problem before I got too worried about it. The university probably has someone you can ask too. Find that person and ask.

However, there's no contract where there is no exchange of value. They can't own it and also not give you something for it.  When I worked at Universities, the ownership was always specified in my contract, whether the work belonged to the school, the government, the grant funder, etc.

Some of this might depend on state law, as well. There was a case in the Perl world where an employer asserted rights to open source code because New York law states that even work an employee does in the same field unrelated to his employment is also property of the employer.

If it really matters to you though, find a free law center near you and get an answer from a real lawyer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this, even if you own the license, the school will accuse you of academic misconduct for providing answers to younger students, we had several cases like this at Ohio State.

Yes, I think that's stupid too, but instructors reuse course work for years and stuff like this would make it very hard for them to combat cheating. If you want to share reusable components, make sure it doesn't explicitly have the answers to any classwork.

**Edit:** If the program you wrote is interesting enough, and doesn't explicitly seem like classwork though, it's definitely worth it to talk to the professor, and maybe even work with him to write a professional journal article about it.

Comment: geeze, don't the profs at OSU know how to make new problems to solve?

Comment: That really depends on the assignment. If it's the answers to an assignment that will be given again, that's one thing. For a one off personalized project, it's a different matter. However, asking the instructor should clear it up.

Comment: The professor could clearly see the code was "stolen" from the open source stuff. It's not very hard to detec copy+pasted code if he is familiar to the copied code

Comment: Its so wrong that people can get in trouble because lecturers are too lazy to make a new assignment each year :(

Comment: @Daniel - have you ever considered that the lecturers have better things to do with their time than create fresh assignments each year?  You really have to question the true motivation of someone who wants to publish solutions to set assignments.

Comment: I question the true motivation of anyone who questions the motivations  of people on such flimsy evidence as this question. There's nothing that suggests lazy lecturers, publishing homework answers so students can cheat, or any other sort of malice or wrongdoing. Maybe this guy just invented the next Linux. Remember where that started?

Comment: This may depend on the academic institution. I've discussed the point of open-sourcing my past University coursework tasks on GitHub with academic integrity staff at my University. The official stance of the University is that lecturers should not repeat the same coursework problems across multiple years, so in theory, my code should be irrelevant to students taking that module in other years.

Answer (score 1):

I've been reading Open Source Licensing: Software Freedom and Intellectual Property Law by Lawrence Rosen, Prentice Hall, New Jersey, 2005. Very good book. I recommend it. He discusses mostly Copyright Law in the context of Software Development, talks briefly about Patents, and mentions Trademarks.

*Copyright protection subsists ... in original works of authorship fixed in any tangible medium of expression ... from which they can be perceived, reproduced, or otherwise communicated, either directly or with the aid of a machine or device ... ( 17 U.S.C. SS 102 ) ... In the case of a work made for hire, the employer or other person for whom the work was prepared is considered the author... ( 17 U.S.C. SS 201[b] )* (Rosen, p 19,20)

In your case Evan, as a student, I recommend taking your time to read this book. It even includes copies of and discusses the Licenses: BSD, MIT, Apache, Artistic, GPL, Mozilla, CPL, and the author's own OSL and AFL. Of course, since the book's publishing in 2005, there are newer versions of those licenses available online. The author recommends, and is a member of, www.opensource.org/.

However, in light of your discloser of solving a problem for class: *Section 101 of the copyright law defines a "work made for hire" as: ... 2 a work specifically ordered or commissioned for use as: ... answer material for a test ...*(http://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ01.pdf] April 2012, p2)

I suppose one could argue that you were ordered to create answer material for a test: but are you not the one who might be considered the employer? Maybe that would depend upon whether you attend a public or private school? I agree that it is just rude to publish answers to quizes/tests but I don't believe that is your intent. At this point I would recommend discussing it further with your professor and take his advice to further your development beyond the scope of just an answer for a test into a truly original work of authorship.

However, from what I believe, and perhaps I am slightly presumptuous: It's all yours to with it what you wish. Realize that, unless they agree to whichever license you propose, nobody may copy your work without infringing on your copyright - enforcing and proving that right requires a few extra steps as briefly described in the copyright.gov publication.

Good Luck Mr Evan. I was delighted and envious to hear about you wonderful summer: I hope, like you said, next summer will be even better. Intellectual property is a concept I often stumble over but I hope to be fearless moving forward as I continue to enlighten myself with such books.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote a paper for an English or history class, you'd own that, wouldn't you? It's your work, and if someone else copied it and turned it in, that would be plagiarism and presumably they'd fail the project at the very least.

Comment: Plagiarism is unrelated to rights ownership. No matter who owns the rights, plagiarism is still plagiarism.

Comment: @brian d foy: plagiarism certainly has to do with rights; one who plagiarized didn't have the right to claim the work as his own. the one who did the work, does have that right.

Comment: It's plagiarism despite the owner, whether university or writer. My publishers have rights to my works, but they don't claim someone else wrote them.

Answer (score 0):

If you were paid to write said code, whomever paid you owns the rights to the code. If you were not paid (like for a class project), you own all the rights to the code.

Comment: Just being paid does not determine rights. It's a matter of local laws and contractual agreements.